# Get data when scrolling Recyclerview according to position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image: RecyclerView at the Bottom]

How to get the data when scrolling RecyclerView for the particular position? I have a list of items which will show the user about the upcoming events(dynamically). I need to fetch the event details when it is positioned at center, to change the position of marker. Sorry, I can't show the code. If you need more details please comment here.

Comment: if i swipe, another event will be placed there instead of which i clicked. Hence, I can't use click listener. I can swipe second event left side to get third event.

Comment: Consider to apply this class "https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener" and do your logic in `onScroll()` method of it.

Comment: am already using addOnScrollListener to get the position of the event, but I need to change the marker location according to Latitude and Longitude. I'm not sure that addOnScrollListener should be used in adapter or in activity.

Comment: If it is not enough means ask me to add whatever you need @V-rund Puro-hit

Comment: well you refused to show your code. it is always good to add necessary code to get solution to your problem.

Comment: okay, i'll add the sample code mate @V-rund Puro-hit

Answer (score 0):

You must fetch the location data inside your reyclerview adapter's onBindViewHolder.

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder> {
         private List<Wrapper> dashboardList; //
         public Adapter(List<Wrapper> dashboardList) {
                this.dashboardList = dashboardList;

            }

        @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

                Wrapper data = dashboardList.get(position);
                holder.tv_price.setText(data.getPrice());
                holder.tv_address.setText(data.getAddress());
                fetchLocation(data.getLocation());
        }
        public void fetchLocation(String location)
        {
        //Code for location search
        }
```